# Return subfolders of current url in PHP

Tags: php, url, string

**I want:**

```
$path = dirname('http://www.domain.com/folder1/folder2/folder3/folder4');

echo $path;
```

**To return:**

folder1/folder2/folder3/folder4

I want it to work with all possible alternatives of the URL eg.:

http://www.domain.com/folder1/folder2/folder3/folder4

http://www.domain.com/folder1/folder2/folder3/folder4/

http://folder1.domain.com/folder2/folder3/folder4/index.html

http://www.domain.com/folder1/folder2/folder3/folder4/index.html

http://domain.com/folder1/folder2/folder3/folder4/index.html

How do I do that in PHP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [`parse_url`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) would be the easiest:

`parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH)`

After doing that you will have the path. However if there is an actual file like `index.html` then youll need to detect and remove that.

Comment: It works for my function :) Not all the exampele links tough. Many thanks.

Comment: Ended up doing like this: $link = 'http://www.domainname.com/folder1/folder2/folder3/folder4';

$domain_and_slash = http://www.domainname.com . '/';

$address_without_site_url = str_replace($domain_and_slash, '', $link);